# Automate Jekyll page.categories according to directory structure

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

**Goal**

Make Jekyll post have their own category according to directory structure.
e.g.) `_post/category1/category2/post-content.md` must have categories of `['category1', 'category2']`(I guess Jekyll deals with categories as an array).
The point is, making 1) no need to specify category in `Front Matter` and 2) auto categorize every posts by directory structure .

**Description**

Official Jekyll document says `Categories are derived from the directory structure above the _post directory. For example, a post at /work/code/_posts/2008-12-24-closures.md would have this field set to ['work', 'code'].`
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/

1. If it is possible, I would joyfully use this function. The problem is, I have no idea how to make `_post` dir to be located *in* other directories. I thought `_post` dir have to be in root dir, so for me positioning post in path like `/work/code/_posts/2008-12-24-closures.md` seems impossible. Is it possible? or not possible?
2. If `1.` is *impossible*, how can I match categories and dir-struct for every post? I don't want to do it manually for every posts.
   I tried to use `{{ page.path }}` to make it automated, but 2 problem I faced. 1) not sure `Liquid(template engine)` support full ruby functionality like `File.basename` for parsing. 2) not sure if codes like parsing can be done in `Front Matter`. For instance, I tried `categories: {{ page.path | array_to_sentence_string }}` in `Front Matter` but it ended up in an error.

any solution for these issues? Or there is no way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're following the directions properly: you can use either folder structure, though the latter is preferred.

The problem is that the special directory is `_posts` PLURAL, not `_post` singular.

Comment: Oh God thx! Now I see dir structure works.. Anyway, what do you mean by 'the latter is preferred'? any recomandation link or more detailed explation for that?